# missing expression error occured in case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have source table `Test` contains `id` column, target table `testm` consist of `id , col2` . Could please assist me to get rid of this error.

```
test (source)                  

 id                              
---                              
 10                     
 10 
 20 
 20 
 20 
 30 
 30 
 40
```

Target

```
testm 

id  col2                
--  ----                
10  1                 
10  2         
20  1          
20  2          
20  3          
30  1          
30  2          
40  1
```

The query:

```
select id, (case id 
            when 10 then select count(id) from test where id =10
            when 20 then select count(id) from test where id =20
            when 30 then select count(id) from test where id =30
            when 40 then select count(id) from test where id =40
else 0 END ) col2 from test
```

throws the error:

> missing expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the desired output I guess that you want to number each occurrence of an id by groups; if this is the case using the row_number analytical function should do what you want:

```
select id, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as col2
from test
order by id;
```

See this sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81ad2/1)

Given you sample source data this would be the output:

```
| ID | COL2 |
|----|------|
| 10 |    1 |
| 10 |    2 |
| 20 |    1 |
| 20 |    2 |
| 20 |    3 |
| 30 |    1 |
| 30 |    2 |
| 40 |    1 |
```

Comment: Hi @jpw thank for quick reply. It satisfied my requirement . is it possible to achieve same o/p with case statement? Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @affable I don't think it is possible with a case statement, at least I can't think of any way.